# How to understand robot orientation from quaternion yaw angle

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this line of code

```
geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(currentth);
```

Where currentth is the angle in radian to represent the pose of the robot.
Then i am making the assignment

```
odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;
```

where i do the propagation. In another node i have a callback as follows

```
void odometryCallback (const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr &odom)
{
// ROS_INFO("ODOMETRY RETRIEVED FROM ODOMETRY NODE and orientation is %f",robotCurrentTheta );
  currentX = odom->pose.pose.position.x;
  currentY = odom->pose.pose.position.y;
  robotCurrentTheta= odom->pose.pose.orientation.w; // not sure here
  ROS_INFO("ODOMETRY RETRIEVED FROM ODOMETRY NODE and orientation is %f %f %f %f",
  odom->pose.pose.orientation.x,odom->pose.pose.orientation.y,odom->pose.pose.orientation.z,odom->pose.pose.orientation.w );
}
```

Now how i can obtain robot's orientation in radian?
am i missing something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41233/how-to-understand-robot-orientation-from-quaternion-yaw-angle/) by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2012-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do it like this:

```
  tf::Pose pose;
  tf::poseMsgToTF(odom->pose.pose, pose);
  double yaw_angle = tf::getYaw(pose.getRotation());
```

Haven't tested this actual snippet, but should work. It's also advisable to [get a basic idea what quaternions are](http://answers.ros.org/question/30340/problem-in-geometry_msgspose/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-07-18**:
And if anyone wants to know how to do the same thing in python, check out this question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/41825/tfgetyaw-in-python/)

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-09-08**:
`#include <tf/tf.h>`